# How to implement navigation drawer button ( hamburger ) which animates to back button when drawer open

Tags: android, animation, back-button, drawer, hamburger-menu

I have been looking to find this for quite some time but couldn't find any solution.

I want to implement this kind of button which looks like a hamburger navigation drawer button when drawer is closed.But when it is opened the icon animates and convert to a 'back button' as show in the image.

[image: button behavior image]

Comment: you want to keep the arrow when the drawer close?

Comment: The easiest method would be a sprite sheet.  When clicked a javascript loop runs incrementing (or decrementing) the frame offset, making a different sprite in a larger spritesheet visible.

Comment: no, i want to animate it back to the hamburger icon

Comment: @Draco18s Sprites are not part of Android sdk.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, the v7 `ActionBarDrawerToggle` does that.

Comment: @Nikola While fair, I meant it in a general term.  It is always possible to create your own sprite system either with one image and a clipping mask or multiple images swapped out in rapid succession.

Comment: @Mike M yes i tried using the v7 ActionBarDrawerToggle, but the button which it showed me was only a 'back button' with no animation at all

Comment: @Draco18s i can implement it using sprites or multiple images but it wont be as smooth like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. The official implementation is in the `appcompat-v7` library, and it requires that you be using `AppCompatActivity` and all its trimmings (e.g., `Theme.AppCompat` or children).

If you are using the native action bar, given some time, you can cross-port the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` from source to work with the native action bar. It took me an hour or two, IIRC.

Comment: yes i tried using the v7 ActionBarDrawerToggle, but the button which it showed me was only a 'back button' with no animation at all

Comment: @FlyingMonkey: Then perhaps you should consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you supply your code and explain your symptoms. Perhaps somebody can point out where you are going wrong. Make sure that you are forwarding all the requested events to the toggle (`onConfigurationChanged()`, `onPostCreate()`, `onOptionsItemSelected()`).

Comment: thank you for your answer.It was ActionBarDrawerToggle appcompat-v7.It was not working properly before because i did had a appcompact-v4 jar in my lib directory which was messing things up.